# Find a node using partial searches

Tags: java, xml, xpath

sample:

```
...
<PEOPLE>
    <PERSON>JOHN, the fighter<PERSON/>
    <PERSON>SALLY, the visionary<PERSON/>
    <PGROUP>
        <PERSON>YOYO<PERSON/>
        <PERSON>BENJI<PERSON/>
    </PGROUP>
    <PERSON>builders<PERSON/>
    <PERSON>cleaners<PERSON/>
    <PGROUP>
        <PERSON>Clowny, good person<PERSON/>
        <PERSON>Clownee, bad person<PERSON/>
    </PGROUP>
    <PERSON>Gentleman<PERSON/>
</PEOPLE>
...
```

I want to plug in a string and find that person (if exists):
    John,
    builder,
    clown *(should return the first occurrence => Clowny, good person)*,
    fighter,
    ...

I have tried these things but none seem to give me a result or a result i want:

//PERSON will select all the persons; contains(Person,'"+searchStr+"'); //PERSON[1] will select 3 persons; //PERSON[PERSON='YOYO'] doesnt work

none of these have worked so far. I want the full name to be returned.

**EDIT:**

This returns 1 if the searchStr is found (input is exact). without count it returns PEOPLE. Appending the expression with /PERSON always returns the first person if the person searched for was found.

**count(//PEOPLE[//PERSON="Clowny, good person"])**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am going to leave this question up if somebody needs it in the future.**

The right approach is to look for the text()

```
//PERSON[contains(text(),"vision")]/text()
```

Selecting the PERSON where the PERSON's text() contains the searchStr then return it's text()